# How to connect to a database with all saved connections at a time in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have around 20 DB connections in Oracle SQL Developer and to connect each separate connection eats my time so I want to know any option to connect all DB connections using single click or minimum efforts.

Comment: You can connect once for all database and save the passwords, as and when you click on database it will be connected and will open workbook in sqldeveloper.

Comment: Thanks, @Mansi. I have saved all passwords but still, to connect 1 DB connection it takes around 1 minute and for 20 connections I'm wasting 20 minutes daily which I want save for to do more work.

Comment: In general, a connection probably shouldn't take a minute. Have you looked into that? Fixing connection time would solve most of your pain.

Comment: Thanks, @thatjeffsmith. My connection time is more than 3 minutes some times so I worried and put this question here.

Comment: open up the View - Log - Statements panel...see if there are any offending 'bad' SQLs there that are slowing down your connection times

Comment: What I found after trial and error that if I shut down my machine and restart then it takes less time to connect even less than 10 seconds.

Comment: In SQLDEVELOPER I just select the DB connection name from the dropdown and when it starts connecting, then I click on X button and again I select some other DB Connection, I repeat this for all required connections and it saves my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found after trial and error that if I shut down my machine and restart then it takes less time to connect even less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to connect more than one database at a time.

So it would be 20 mouse-clicks, and 20 right-arrows to open 20 connections.

I would advise you to open them as needed, as connections are not cheap, client or server perspective. And we run a ton of queries on a connect, so it's not a simple thing in and of itself either.

Comment: Thanks, @thatjeffsmith. You are correct connections are not cheap, But I work daily on all DBs so its time waste and headache for 20 mouse-clicks, and 20 right-arrows to open 20 connections.